# Error Apache when I upload a Image

Tags: apache, post, header

when I upload a File, return a HTTP error, I thought is a permision directory, but in the Apache.error.log

```
[:error] [pid 15697] [client 84.127.226.119:57773] [client 84.127.226.119] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 2). Pattern match "^POST$" at REQUEST_METHOD. [file "/etc/modsecurity/custom/20_bruteforce.conf"] [line "44"] [id "210"] [msg "Accept header required"] [hostname "www.adginteriorismo.com"] [uri "/admin/uploadify/uploadify.php"] [unique_id "WHicpFJihsAAADqYz0UAAAAD"]
```

How I can Fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have ModSecurity installed and have configured it with a rule to not allow POST requests.

ModSecurity is a Web Application Firewall (WAF) add on to Apache and can be quite complicated to understand.

Easiest option is to comment out that rule (line 44 in /etc/modsecurity/custom/20_bruteforce.conf) and restart Apache - though maybe someone added that rule for a good reason.